# Autodesk Forge call for .gltf object for arcgis map

Tags: autodesk-forge, arcgis

how can I call for autodesk forge 3D model in .gltf (or .obj) file to use it in arcgis javascript app?
Thank You

Comment: If I well understand, your need is to extract 3D model from Forge into glTF or OBJ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate obj through the workflow described in [this tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/xtract-geometry-from-source-file/).

You can also take advantage of forge-convert-utils to generate gltf (refer [here](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils#nodejs)). This method takes advantage of a SVF, covered [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-file4viewer/)